# Setting SCHEMABINDING and IsDeterministic for a CLR function

Tags: sqlclr, sql-server-2012

I have an existing C# CLR runtime function that I am using with SQL Server 2012. I would like to set the `IsDeterministic` and `SCHEMABINDING` options on this function so I can use it for persisting a computed column in a table.

Here is the alter statement:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[authorityFromURI](@URI [nvarchar](4000))
RETURNS [nvarchar](4000) WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [KDPSqlServerProject].[UserDefinedFunctions].[authorityFromURI]
```

How should this alter statement be modified to set these options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the IsDeterminstic property within the function code itself, e.g

```
[SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true, IsPrecise = true [...])]
```

To make it schemabinding:

```
RETURNS NVARCHAR(4000)
WITH SCHEMABINDING, EXECUTE AS CALLER
```

That said, I haven't tested these options together with persistence...

Comment: I changed my c# code to:
public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true, IsPrecise = true)]

    public static SqlString authorityFromURI(SqlString URI)
    {
and it all works perfectly, including persistence. Note that I did not need to set "with schemabinding"

Comment: @JonnyBoats and Aaron: 1) `SCHEMABINDING` is not a valid option for SQLCLR functions, and 2) while it does not appear to be an issue in this particular case (i.e. getting the authority of a URI), it should be noted that you should only set `IsDeterministic`, and optionally `IsPrecise`, to `true` IF they actually are. If you set them to `true` when in fact they are not, you will see some "odd" behavior.